# Error in Change menu item at onResume()

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to change menu item background programatically but I have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.getItem(int)' on a null object reference
```

I used this code.

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    menu.getItem(1).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(N_Wall_new.this, R.drawable.bil2));
}
```

So what should I do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Menu is not initialized in onResume method.

Comment: where is your `menu` variable initialized?

Comment: @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_first, menu);
        this.menu = menu;

        return true;
    }

Comment: if (sharedpreferences.getInt(like_stat, 1) == 1) {

                menu.getItem(1).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(N_Wall_new.this, R.drawable.bil2));

            }

Comment: check the state for menu if it is destroyed.

Comment: as override methods destroys their states. you have to save the menu

Comment: how to do that , and where ?

Comment: you can save it in bundle of the activity which you are using or by initializing it in extra class as session controller.

Comment: sorry , i don't now how to (save extra class as session controller)